# angular 8 how to use component multiple times in parent component with different action

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular8

I have a component that can be used multiple times in parent component with diffrent action. How would i get my component clicked event to parent.

My Component that can be used multiple times:

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-card',
        template: `<button (click)="onClickMe()">select</button>`
    })
    export class MyCardComponent {
    onClickMe() {
       //if my-card in parent component is type 1 do some thing
       //if my-card in parent component is type 2 do some thing
    }
   }
```

my parent component html :

```
<div>
   <p>Type 1<p>
  <my-card></my-card>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Type 2<p>
  <my-card></my-card>
</div>
```

how can i do it?

Comment: why not use a `@Input` https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding ?

Comment: Actually both `@Input()` and `@Ouput()` can be used here.

Comment: Thank you , but when parent component is initial,type is 1 and 2.then in myCard component @input type value is 1 or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With @Output

`@Output() someClickAction = new EventEmitter<void>();`

You can also send some data just change the void to the right data type.

Then in `onClickMe()` just call `emit` on the `someClickAction` property.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-card',
  template: `<button (click)="onClickMe()">select</button>`
})
export class MyCardComponent {
  @Output() someClickAction = new EventEmitter<void>();

  onClickMe() {
    this.someClickAction.emit();

  }
}
```

In html it would look like this.

```
<div>
  <p>Type 1</p>
  <my-card (someClickAction)="someFunction()"></my-card>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Type 2</p>
  <my-card (someClickAction)="someOtherFunction()"></my-card>
</div>
```

### With @Input()

Here you wouldn't send info about click to child but you will specify type in parent and child will behave based on the value.

By `@Input` you specify you attribute for your component

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-card',
  template: `<button (click)="onClickMe()">select</button>`
})
export class MyCardComponent {
  @Input() type: number;

  onClickMe() {
    if(this.type === 1) {

    } else if(this.type === 2) {

    }
  }
}
```

In HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Type 1</p>
  <my-card [type]="1"></my-card>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Type 2</p>
  <my-card [type]="2"></my-card>
</div>
```

**You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)**

Comment: Thank you , but when parent component is initial,type is 1 and 2.then in myCard component @input type value is 1 or 2?

Comment: @MohammadFiroozi Sorry I made a mistake in the code now it's fixed

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question well but the value is based on the value of `[type]` in HTML because everytime you use `<my-card>` in HTML you create new Instance of the component called MyCard

Comment: Hi @all just want to add something in it if have multiple components just like this then how can I get the value of all components at a same time?

Answer (score 0):

Use EventEmitters (https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). You can fire eventEmitter with specific value inside of it to parent component, in this case you could declare card type.

Children:

```
onClickMe() {
       this.myEventEmitter.emit( // any data)
    }
```

Parent html:

```
<my-card (myEventEmitter)="anyFunction($event)></my-card>
```

Parent ts:

```
anyFunction(args) {
       // Do something by type that is declared in args
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use an input

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-card',
        template: `<button (click)="onClickMe()">select</button>`
    })
    @Input() type;
    export class MyCardComponent {
    onClickMe() {
       if (this.type === 1= {
           // do something
       } else {// do something }
    }
   }
```

if you have more type use a switch... your parent component html :

```
<div>
   <p>Type 1<p>
  <my-card [type]=1></my-card>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Type 2<p>
  <my-card [type]=2></my-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With @Input xyzParameter you can input values from a parent component into a child. 
In your case that way you can control the childs behavior.

```html
  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-card',
        template: `<button (click)="onClickMe()">select</button>`
    })
    export class MyCardComponent {

    @Input() type: number; // that value is taken from the parent´s template

    onClickMe() {
       //if my-card in parent component is type 1 do some thing
       //if my-card in parent component is type 2 do some thing
    }
   }
```

my parent component html :

```html
<div>
   <p>Type 1<p>
  <my-card [type]="1"></my-card>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Type 2<p>
  <my-card [type]="2"></my-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , but when parent component is initial,type is 1 and 2.then in myCard component @input type value is 1 or 2?